# How to hide subfolder name from script url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I want to hide subfolder name from script url:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/abc/cde/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I want to change href="/abc/cde/css/bootstrap.min.css"

To

href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Descriptions:

I am using shared hosting.
And my site is inside folder abc/cde/

I am using following .htaccess at root folder(/)

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myhost.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/cde/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/cde/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myhost.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ abc/cde/index.php [L]
```

Everthing seems Okay .I am able to access www.myhost.com directly.

**But**

when I am using (View source), Subfolder as visible there

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/abc/cde/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

**I want to hide This path also.**

**FYI:I am using Cakephp**

Answer (score 1):

**Rewrite rule cannot change your HTML source.** You need to change your script tag as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Then have your rules as below:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# to route css and js
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/ /abc/cde%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myhost\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/cde/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abc/cde/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myhost\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ abc/cde/index.php [L]
```